# Django - how to override form template tag in html

Tags: python, html, django, forms, overriding

i am working on project which is not in English language. I have encountered a little problem during registration.

In my registration html i have :

```
...
<form action="" style="text-align: center" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<ul style = "text-align: left">
{{user_form.as_p}}
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Užsiregistruoti" onclick="validateForm()"/>

</form>
...
```

and now the text is by default in english. The `{{user_form.as_p}}` takes values from my forms.py:

```
...
fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
...
```

is there a way to leave forms values unchanged, and rewrite the html part in my own language? how do i do that? I cant just take the generated parts of html and translate it, it wont work that way.

Comment: you mean about "{{user_form.as_p}}", you want to write in your own language.

Comment: You need to enable Django's `I18N` features for this. It is a bit of a broad topic, but it is very well [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/). After the basic setup, you can then translate labels on your forms to any language that is setup in the settings. In a form e.g. like `your_name = forms.CharField(label=_('Your name'), max_length=100)` or if your form derives from a model, then through the `verbose_name` attribute in your models.

Comment: :) I somehow figured you were working on a project that needs to support multiple languages (which isn't at all what you wrote). If your project needs to be in a single language then of course the answer by @shellbye is much simpler and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `verbose_name` in `model` like this:

```
field = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="your_language_here")
```

More info see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name)

If your `form` didn't come from a 'Model`, you can use`label` instead like this:

```
field = forms.CharField(label="your_language_here")
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.label).

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the generated HTML (except for the CSRFtoken wich you must put as {% csrf_token %}) and change the values inside the  tags.

If you want to do it more maintainable and less error-prone, I will change the form labels https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#label in your forms.py.

Anyway, the form validation errors are going to be in English. so if you want to do it right, you must read the [django docs on translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/).